# How to pass parameter from yaml file to our code

Tags: c#, selenium, azure-pipelines, web-testing

For example, I have a software called "mytest.exe" and I have defined a pipeline to test this app on 2 agents.

Should I be able to call it from the yaml file of a pipeline with different parameters, like this

agent1: mytest.exe --login=user1 --password=password1

agent2: mytest.exe --login=user2 --password=password2

Answer (score 0):

you could use format expressions for this purpose:

```
- bash: ${{ format('mytest.exe --login={0} --password={1}', parameters.user, $(my_password_variable)) }}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#format